# How Do I Format .json Files In Bracket?

Tags: json, adobe-brackets

Ok so, im trying to edit files for some programs im downloading. And almost all of them use .json files. I try to open them with Atom, Notepad++, Sublime Text Editor 3, And Brackets. But when I open them, all of the code is on 1 line, exept when I use brackets. It still says everything is on 1 line, evan know it looks like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNB51.jpg

When I try to enter more text In the file, it just says this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuyI1.jpg

How do I make it so it stills stays on that one line, but not have to make everything like this.
imgur.com/a/HmJOD

I know im really bad at explaining >.> you dont have to tell me that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should download Pretty Json.

Here is the link. 
For more convenience find the Setting in Bracket and download from there so it will auto install and stuff.  :)

[link removed, link leads to malware]

Comment: One thing that inst clear to me is, well I can format everything with this extension, but how do I add more lines >.>
https://imgur.com/a/hw084 Like doing the exact opposite of that.

Answer (score -1):

Use **Visual studio code**. It comes with formatter in built. No need to install plugin/package, setup short cut etc. Just right click and format file. Or can use existing short cut of-course.